# PHP file inclusion error

Tags: php

I am trying to create a **config.php** file similar as wordpress does. My code does create the file but i have been facing problem with file inclusions. I have a file **defines.php** in includes directory inside admin directory. But when, i include the file **defines.php** in my **setup-config.php** (in admin directory), i get the following error

```
Notice: Constant SS_ADMIN_BASEDIR already defined in
C:\xampp\htdocs\cmsproject\ab_admin\defines.php on line 2

Notice: Constant SS_ADMIN_INCLUDES already defined in
C:\xampp\htdocs\cmsproject\ab_admin\defines.php on line 3

Notice: Constant SS_ADMIN_IMAGES already defined in
C:\xampp\htdocs\cmsproject\ab_admin\defines.php on line 4

Notice: Constant SS_ADMIN_CSS already defined in
C:\xampp\htdocs\cmsproject\ab_admin\defines.php on line 5

Notice: Constant SS_ADMIN_JAVASCRIPT already defined in
C:\xampp\htdocs\cmsproject\ab_admin\defines.php on line 6
```

My defines.php file in include directory is as follows:

```
<?php
     define('SS_ADMIN_BASEDIR',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'\\');
     define('SS_ADMIN_INCLUDES','includes\\');
     define('SS_ADMIN_IMAGES','images\\');
     define('SS_ADMIN_CSS','css\\');
     define('SS_ADMIN_JAVASCRIPT','javascript\\');
?>
```

A part of my setup-config.php is as follows:

```
<?php
     require_once('includes/defines.php');
     require_once(SS_ADMIN_BASEDIR . SS_ADMIN_INCLUDES . 'functions.php');

     define('SS_ROOT_DIR',dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/');
     //more code goes here, not related to the question
?>
```

What i do in the root directory(index.php) is detect the config.php file and redirect to setup-config.php
File index.php is as follows:

```
<?php
     //First and foremost what we do is check if the config.php exists or not
     $fileName = dirname(__FILE__).'/config.php';
     if(!file_exists($fileName) or is_dir($fileName))
     header('Location:ab_admin/setup_config.php');
     else
     echo "Load the template";
?>
```

So far, I know this error is displayed when a file is included multiple times in script using require or include. But i used require_once here, but still have problem.
Does the version of xampp affect this? I was using xampp 1.7.3 and this code worked fine but i upgraded to xampp 1.8.3 and now things got messed up.
***Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.***

Comment: For hosting on non-Windows servers too, use `/` instead of `\\ `.

Comment: was using / before but after the error i replaced it with \\.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if defined! but this is a workaround.
best practice is to never need to redefine something.

```
defined('SS_ADMIN_BASEDIR') or define('SS_ADMIN_BASEDIR', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'\\');
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked, but can you tell me the reason it happened so.

Comment: sorry didn't break down you're code. just posted the solution for the alert "Already defined".  
but it looks like you include/require the same file multiple times.